# Does a linearly independent combination of $n$ group elements generate $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working through some group theory stuff and I have a question for you guys.

I know that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a vector space, and a group. Now if I think of it as a vector space, I know a linearly independent collection of $n$ vectors will generate the space.

If I think of it as a group, does a linearly independent combination of $n$ group elements still generate the entire space?

So if I have a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by $3$ linearly independent group elements, that subgroup equals the whole group, right?

Answer (score 1):

A "$\mathbb{Z}$-vector space" should really be called a "$\mathbb{Z}$-module" (since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field).  Modules over non-fields behave differently than modules over fields (i.e. vector spaces).  In particular, unlike the situation for fields:

1. Modules need not have bases.  For example, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module that has no basis. If a module has a basis, it is called a *free* module.
2. Even if a module does have a basis of $n$ elements, that does not mean that *any* set of $n$ linearly independent elements will span the whole space.

So this last statement is incorrect: "So if I have a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ generated by 3 linearly independent group elements, that subgroup equals the whole group, right?"  It does not.  You can see a simple counterexample: Consider the submodule $2\mathbb{Z}^3 \subset \mathbb{Z}^3$.  It can be generated by 3 linearly independent elements, but it is not all of $\mathbb{Z}^3$.